Late 1990s to early 2000s movie that involved aliens and meat everywhere
Here's what I can remember:

there was meat everywhere
tall octopus-like alien that "made" the meat (unsure)
the tall alien detects with a lighthouse kind of eye
smaller aliens that cant see or hear or have a general disability like that
scene where guy and maybe young girl are in a basement and have to avoid the alien
girl runs out, guy goes after her and gets caught
I watched this at a motel in 2013 on cable, looks like it came out late 1990s to early 2000s.


Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Just to confirm, this was a live-action movie in English?  What country did you see it in?  What was happening with the meat?

hi ty! yes it was live action, i saw it in california. i thiiinnkk it might have held eggs for the aliens but im unsure

What did the smaller aliens look like? Also octopus-like or different?

This sounds very much like War of the Worlds with Tom Cruise from 2005.  Aliens invade earth with building sized war machines, and the protagonist must find safety and protect his son and daughter.

there was meat everywhere

There was a red alien plant growing everywhere that had a meaty look to it

tall octopus-like alien that "made" the meat (unsure)

The Alien's war machines sprayed a red mixture everywhere as a fertilizer or something for the red plant, which was implied to be made from ground up humans.  The war machines also had tentacles and long skinny legs, so they could be described as octopus like.

the tall alien detects with a lighthouse kind of eye

The alien war machines were very tall tripods, with a bright centre eye/death-ray thing that could be described as looking like a light house.

smaller aliens that cant see or hear or have a general disability like
that

The actual aliens that drove the war machines were our size, but they didn't seem deaf or blind.

scene where guy and maybe young girl are in a basement and have to
avoid the alien

The protagonist and his daughter hide in a basement at one point.  There is also another man there as well.

girl runs out, guy goes after her and gets caught

The protagonist's daughter gets caught, and the protagonist goes after her and gets caught.

I watched this at a motel in 2013 on cable, looks like it came out
late 1990s to early 2000s.

It's from 2005, so that matches.

Another movie that comes to my mind is Cloverfield (2008). It is a tall monster and it has parasites that falls off its body. But not sure if there are any connection with the "meat" here.
